# How to make two divs top and bottom

Tags: html, css

I have this menu and a slider but the menu is on top of the slide and it cover some of the picture.Can any one help me to make the slider on the bottom of the menu exactly.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Let see your code. Add it to y0ur question

Comment: use margin-top or margin-bottom on either of them

Comment: Try give the menu and a slider Positions this maybe fix that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `<div class="space"></div>` before the slider and giving it a `height:50px;` in css (the same height as the navigation.)

```css
body {margin: 0; padding:0;}
ul {
  background: #000;
  color:#fff;
  line-height:50px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
}
ul li {
  display:inline-block;
}
.space {
height:50px;

}
.slider {
  background:red;
  height:350px;
  width:600px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
<div class="space"></div>
<div class="slider">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but I want to make the menu fixed and I add the position and it cover the slide but when I remove the position it works..

Comment: I've updated my original answer using `<div class="space"></div>` before the slider and giving it a `height:50px;` in css (the same height as the navigation.)

Comment: Good you are welcome, upvote the answer so we know it is resolved.